# JNLP java.security.AccessControlException with TargetDataLine.open()?

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start

I have the following line which caused this error message run under JNLP :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.sound.sampled.AudioPermission record)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)


TargetDataLine targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
```

How to fix it ? Or does that mean in JNLP, we can't record sound ?

PS : I'm not running it in all-permissions mode, because it requires a 3rd party paid cert. to sign the jar before I can submit my app to Sun's Java Store. I wonder if there's any other way, like using JNLP's FileSaveService / FileOpenService ?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to your JNLP (sibling to `</infomration>`, does it work?

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

By default, you do not have access outside the applet sandbox, including audio.